# How can I get a PrimeFaces widgetVar function list?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can someone redirect me to a web resource, where I can find list of all `widgetVar` JavaScript functions list, eg. toggle(), show(), hide () etc etc.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: What about the PrimeFaces documentation?

Comment: Note that you can also use .jq on the widgetVar (after e.g. PF('widgetVar')) and with that then call jQuery functions like .show() or .hide().

Answer (score 12):

### Before PrimeFaces 10

You can find the [JavaScript sources of all widgets at GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces). For example: [`datatable.js`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js).

You can also open your browser's JavaScript console and type:

```
PF('yourWidget').__proto__
```

That will give you the properties list (including functions). Try it at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

```
PF('customersTable').__proto__
```

In Chrome this results in an object with collapsible nodes:

```
▼ c {SORT_ORDER: Object}
  ▶ SORT_ORDER: Object
  ▶ _render: function()
  ▶ addGhostRow: function()
  ▶ addResizers: function()
  ▶ addRow: function()
  ▶ addSelection: function(a)
  ▶ addSortMeta: function(a)
  ...
```

Also, next to the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) there is also [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/) you should have a look at. For many components the client side API is well documented, see for example: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datatable?id=client-side-api

### PrimeFaces 10 and up

From PrimeFaces 10 there is dedicated [PrimeFaces JavaScript API documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/index.html).