# How to permanently show a p:tooltip?

Tags: primefaces, tooltip

I'm trying to permanently show the `p:tooltip` in a PrimeFaces project I'm working on.
This is my current code:

```
<p:graphicImage id="testImg" name="/img/testImg.jpg" onclick="PF('info').show();" style="cursor: pointer"/> 
<p:tooltip for="testImg" value="further information" position="right" />
<p:dialog widgetVar="info" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true" >
    <h:outputText value="bla bla bla"/>
</p:dialog>
```

I tried this:

```
<p:tooltip for="testImg" value="further information" position="right" showEevent="permanent"/>
```

but it didn't work.

Is there any way to control the tooltip and have it permanently visible without having to mouse over or focus the controlling element?

Comment: So, basically you want to show a text at the right hand side of your image? Why not simply add a text and add the style class `ui-tooltip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, there is no show event called permanent. What you could do is controlling the tooltip with JavaScript using a widget variable. You can assign one for the tooltip using the `widgetVar` attribute. The [tooltip widget](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/tooltip/tooltip.js) has several functions, one of them is `show()` (to show the tooltip).
When the tooltip is shown there is a delay of 150 msec, so set that to 0 to immediately show the tooltip. To prevent the tooltip from being hidden, set the `hideEvent` to some non existing event (like `none`).

Putting it all together:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
  <h:outputText value="Permanent" />
  <p:inputText id="permanent"
               title="Permanent tooltip" />
  <p:tooltip id="permanentTip"
             for="permanent"
             widgetVar="permanentTip"
             showDelay="0"
             hideEvent="none"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<script>
  $(function(){ 
    PF('permanentTip').show();
  });
</script>
```

See also:

- [How can I get a PrimeFaces widgetVar function list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994144/primefaces-widgetvar-functions-list)